# Delimited text layer using coordinates from csv file is not working

Tags: csv, qgis

I am using a csv file with coordinates to create a layer. However, the points do not show on the map and I don't understand why.

[image]

Comment: I expect they do show up, just very small on Null Island. You have set the projection wrong your coordinates are in EPSG:4326 not EPSG:3857

Comment: Thanks, that's it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.